# Sqoop command not working

Tags: sqoop

I am able to start sqoop server but when I am passing `sqoop help` in console, It is saying

> sqoop command not found.

I have exported the sqoop path in bashrc file.

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/local/sqoop/ 
export PATH=$SQOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Its regarding sqoop... which is part of programming and development.. I guess its not related to linux right?

Comment: "command not found" is more a unix-specific error than programming. You should `ls $SPOOP_HOME/bin` and `echo $PATH` to prove to us that the command does, in fact exist. Also, Sqoop2 has a "server", while Sqoop1 does not.

Comment: What do you see in the folder `/usr/local/sqoop/`? If you do `ls -l /usr/local/sqoop/` do you see the bin folder there? Which Hadoop distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .bashrc file,

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/local/sqoop/  
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
```

Update your environment with your new .bashrc file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Here I am assuming /usr/local/sqoop folder exists !!!

Comment: yes it exist... tried that.. but still it is not working